# Magento 2: Changing layout for a theme at store level

Tags: magento2

I am recently asked a question, that if a customer wants to change his theme pages for a US store to the 2-column layout but in the default theme, the page has a 3-column layout. How we can achieve this.
Is there a way to do it by overriding layout in the same theme.
As far as I understand we need to create two separate themes itself, making default as the parent of the US store theme. Is this the correct solution or any other best solution is there.

Comment: Try via admin panel, go to Stores > Configuration > (select/set Store View) General > Web > Default Layout > Default Page Layout > 2 Columns with Left Bar

Comment: Apologies, setting the Store View to anything other than "Default Config" removes the "Default Page Layout" section settings ...